# How do I count out 24 measures?

Tags: sheet-music, audition

I'm auditioning for a play and the requirement is to prepare 24 measures of a song and perform it vocally. I'm going to be performing Tomorrow from the musical, Annie. How do I count out 24 measures?

Comment: You need to explain this much more carefully: at a first reading it seems that counting is irrelevant, in that if you perform the 24 measures of the song, then you finish after the last measure - no counting needed. Please give much more information if you hope for answers.

Answer (score 4):

1) Find a [recording of  the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrXXV5ut7fc) or have someone perform it so that you can listen to it (repeatedly if necessary)

2) listen to the song, identify the beat.

3) then identify the time signature -- rhythmically the music comes in chunks, most commonly of 4 beats, sometimes 3 or 2, and less common other counts, with an accent especially on the first beat of each chunk.  Tomorrow is in 4.  Each of these groups of 4 beats is one [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_%28music%29) of the song; listen to the song, counting out 1-2-3-4, 1-2-3-4...

4) Count out 24 measures worth of singing -- this is what you should rehearse.

Some comments:

- it doesn't necessarily have to be the first 24 measures.
- In this case, as with many songs, each phrase of the  lyrics spans 4 measures, so counting out 4 measures at a time (1-2-3-4, 2-2-3-4, 3-2-3-4, 4-2-3-4), and then counting these groups of 4 on your fingers, or by making a mark on paper, is a good way to go.
- This song is tricky in that there is an extra measure slipped in in the transition between the first verse and the first chorus, I wouldn't worry about that and just not count it.
- The first two words are "[pick up notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacrusis)" -- the first "will" falls on the first beat of the measure.

If you select the beginning, this works out to the first verse and chorus of the song.

Comment: Consider doing the -last- 24 bars rather than the first - that way you get to impress them with your sustained high note/big finish.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to find sheet music with lyrics? Then it becomes easy.

Every vertical line represents the end of a measure. You count 24 vertical lines and voila: you have 24 measures of your song. Using the lyrics you can orient yourself.

Answer (score -1):

24 measures amounts to a verse and a chorus.  Think of it that way.

I was SO TEMPTED to say..."you can't count a measure?  why are you auditioning for something where you have to count a measure?

Comment: Could be. But not necessarily...

Comment: On the other hand: it is probably what the auditioners have in mind...